# Text not being saved in text file on enter-key press using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, tkinter

I am building a chat GUI. On enter-key press, I want the text fields to be shown on the text box as well as be saved in a file. I do not want to use separate button. It is being shown in the text box correctly but not getting saved in the file. Please tell me how can it be done. This is my first time using tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=1000)
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#username entry
L1 = Label(frame, text="User Name")
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
input_username = StringVar()
input_field1 = Entry(frame, text=input_username, width=10)
input_field1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

#addresee entry
L2 = Label(frame, text="@")
L2.pack(side = LEFT)
input_addresee = StringVar()
input_field2 = Entry(frame, text=input_addresee, width=10)
input_field2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

#user comment entry
L3 = Label(frame, text="Comment")
L3.pack(side = LEFT)
input_usertext = StringVar()
input_field3 = Entry(frame, text=input_usertext, width=100)
input_field3.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

#write to a file
def save():
    text = input_field1.get() + input_field2.get() + input_field3.get() 
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)

#chat box
chats = Text(root)
chats.pack()

def Enter_pressed(event):
    input_get_name = input_field1.get()
    print(input_get_name)
    chats.insert(INSERT, '%s    : ' % input_get_name)
    input_username.set('')

    input_get_add = input_field2.get()
    print(input_get_add)
    chats.insert(INSERT, '@%s   : ' % input_get_add)
    input_addresee.set('')

    input_get_comment = input_field3.get()
    print(input_get_comment)
    chats.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % input_get_comment)
    input_usertext.set('')
    save()

frame2 = Frame(root)
L2_1 = Label(frame2, text="All chats")
L2_1.pack(side = TOP)
input_field1.bind(Enter_pressed)
input_field2.bind(Enter_pressed)
input_field3.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
frame2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are setting the input fields to blank

Here's the solution:

```
def save(text):
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
```

And when calling save:

```
save(input_get_name+": "+input_get_add+": "+input_get_comment)
```